# Run a circuit on "simulator_statevector" of the IBM Quantum Platforms

Tags: quantum-state, simulation, ibm-quantum-devices

I would like to obtain the statevector of a `QuantumCircuit` using the `simulator_statevector` (and Qiskit) of the IBM Quantum Platform, in order to calculate an exact expectation value of an observable.

I managed to do that by using a finite amount of shots, but since the simulator uses the exact statevector, I wonder if there is a way to obtain that statevector.

Answer (score 1):

The more modern and scalable way to get the expectation value of an observable is to use the Estimator primitive [more on primitives here](https://medium.com/qiskit/what-are-qiskit-primitives-9bf63c1eacc7).

### Local solution

Anyways, if you to get the statevector of some circuit follow the example below:

```python
from qiskit import execute, Aer, QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.visualization import array_to_latex

# Here goes your circuit

backend = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
job = execute(qc, backend)
state = job.result().get_statevector()


array_to_latex(state, prefix="\\text{Statevector} = ")
```

Notice that `get_statevector()` is not a measurement.

### On IBMQ cloud

I don't see a way to obtain an analytical expression of the final state vector. Moreover, by running a Bell circuit my own I realized that at the results obtained by `job.result()` there is nothing that could help. Although you can use `job.result().get_counts()` or the local solution which should work just fine.

#### Example

In advance make sure to load your IBM quantum experience account properly.

```python
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram

bell = QuantumCircuit(2)
bell.h(0)
bell.cx(0, 1)
bell.measure_all()

service = QiskitRuntimeService()
sim = service.get_backend("simulator_statevector")
job = sim.run(bell, shots=1000)
plot_histogram(job.result().get_counts())
```

Comment: I think that I was not clear on the question. "simulator_statevector" is a simulator that you can access with the cloud of IBM Quantum Platform. So I don't want to use Aer (i.e. local simulation on my device). The problem is that I don't know how to do something like "get_statevector" in that context.

Comment: Oh ok I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: How did you get the "job" object in the cloud?

Comment: On the example provided the type of `job` is `qiskit_ibm_runtime.runtime_job.RuntimeJob`.